# Import OLD wallet.dat to new Bitcoin core

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet.dat, mac

i made a wallet.dat backup in an old version of bitcoin qt. The mac where i had wallet is dead. In other mac with the last version of bitcoin core when i try to replace the wallet.dat the app crushes. What i am doing wrong?

Comment: Crashes with what message? How are you trying to load the wallet?